# Why sitebricks response with 405 status when using delete method?

Tags: http, servlets, jetty, sitebricks

I am implementing a simple rest service with the 4 http methods get,post, put and delete using sitebricks. trying to send a delete request to the defined service with a WebClient I get a 405 response. Does anyone knows why would I get such response ?

10:22:24.840 [5907955@qtp-6711891-2 - /r/clients/123] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - RESPONSE /r/clients/123  405

This is how I use web client

```
 WebClient client = web().clientOf(delete(123)).transports(String.class).over(Json.class);
    client.delete();
```

here is my delete method

```
 @Delete
  @At("/:id")
  public Reply delete(@Named("id") String id) {
    clientsRepository.delete(id);
    return Reply.saying().ok();
  }
```

I am using Jetty Server.

Answer (score 1):

Response code 405 means that something is configured to not allow the use of the http DELETE method.

I can't speak for sitebricks itself, but servlet spec allows you to disable specific methods.

The `web.xml` of your webapp or the `${jetty.home}/etc/webdefault.xml`, as either could be configured to disallow the use of specific HTTP methods (like TRACE, PUT, DELETE).

Check those files for `<security-constraints>` that might have `<http-method>` declarations for DELETE.

Also note that any code can trigger the 405 response itself.
Since you are seeing this in Sitebricks, possibly a `<filter>` in your web.xml is preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you constructing the request URI properly? Sitebricks returns 405 if there is no handler method. This test case verifies that @Delete does indeed work properly:

https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/blob/master/sitebricks-acceptance-tests/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/example/RestfulWebServiceWithSubpaths2.java

Also as joakime says, do check if any other filters or handlers are firing outside Sitebricks.

Comment: Yes, there is handler method.Also I wonder how to send request data with delete ? with post I can do webClient.post(someData).But, not with delete.